# RSS - Feedjira updates, clock work gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clockwork, feedjira

I am new to rails so I watched railscast #168 to get an understand of how feedjira works. I got an idea how it works now. I got the functionalities to work as well. Where I struggle is at the update section, I can't get the "15 min" update to work.

So I downloaded a gem called "Clockwork" but I can't figure out how to connect the clockwork gem with the updates from feed_entry.rb.
I want the rss feed to update every 15 min and every 1h.

```html
class FeedEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.update_from_feed(feed_url)
    feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
    add_entries(feed.entries)
  end
  
  def self.update_from_feed_continuously(feed_url, delay_interval = 15.minutes)
    feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
    add_entries(feed.entries)
    loop do
      sleep delay_interval
      feed = Feedjira::Feed.update(feed)
      add_entries(feed.new_entries) if feed.updated?
    end
  end
  
  private
  
  def self.add_entries(entries)
    entries.each do |entry|
      unless exists? :guid => entry.id
        create!(
          :name         => entry.title,
          :summary      => entry.summary,
          :url          => entry.url,
          :published_at => entry.published,
          :guid         => entry.id
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```html
<div id="recent_episodes">
  <h3>Recent Railscasts Episodes</h3>
  <ul>
  <% for entry in FeedEntry.all.limit(10).order("published_at DESC") %>
    <li><%= link_to h(entry.name), entry.url %></li>
    <i><%= entry.url %></li>
 
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the code the documentation provides, https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork.

I generated a model call Clock.

But I am not sure how to use it yet.

```html
class Clock < ActiveRecord::Base
require 'clockwork'
module Clockwork
  handler do |job|
    puts "Running #{job}"
  end

  # handler receives the time when job is prepared to run in the 2nd argument
  # handler do |job, time|
  #   puts "Running #{job}, at #{time}"
  # end

  every(10.seconds, 'frequent.job')
  every(3.minutes, 'less.frequent.job')
  every(1.hour, 'hourly.job')

  every(1.day, 'midnight.job', :at => '00:00')
end

end
```

Comment: No, I didn't. I tried another way but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the update functionallity was removed from feedjira due to serious problems detecting new feeds.

See https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira/commit/6f56516934a9bdb8691f2bbe98be0f2b7c25b7ea

The website is updated now as well http://feedjira.com/

I am also interested in a library that is capable to detect feed updates without downloading all items. Any suggestions?